# Limit loop through array by key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array

```
$hidArr[$k]
```

When I output it to view all values like this

```
print_r($hidArr[0]);
```

I see results

> 110210 110211 110212 110213

Basically my array is:

I need to loop though that array and output only the results where $k == 0

```
foreach ($hidArr[$k] AS $ha) {
   echo $ha;
}
```

I get no results. What am I missing?

Comment: How/where is `$k` defined? You're question is a bit unclear.

Comment: foreach($hidArr as $k => $ha){ echo $ha; }

Comment: here you are missing key, foreach ($hidArr[$k] as $key=> $ha) {
   echo $key;
}

Comment: avoid confusing, post your array `$hidArr` and expected result

Comment: If you want to print array value where key is 0, just do print($hidArr[0])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop only the $hideArr[0] array to list all elements in it

```
foreach ($hidArr[0] AS $ha) {
    echo $ha;
}
```